# Creating local server on an Android device

Tags: java, android, networking

I have an idea for an application where one device is a server, and other devices connect to this server.

The clients would send data and call HTTP requests (or whatever is equal to them in this case), and the server would receive the request and act on it.

I understand there is such a thing as Sockets, but does this fulfill my requirement? Will I be able to call requests on the other device?

**Example usage:** The client clicks the + button, and the server increments the value.

Comment: Have you written a client/server app using sockets on a PC before?

Comment: Yeah, We call it Bluetooth connection

Comment: I haven't used sockets on PC, I've seen a socket on PC to Mobile though, but I know PCs are different in some terms.

Comment: @Nadna Z but isn't Bluetooth limited to a certain number of devices? 3-4? My app might used 10+ devices.

Comment: You can open and write to sockets on Android just like a PC.  You could pretty much write the framework on a PC, and then just embed it in an Android app.

Comment: By writing data to a socket, does that mean I can use something like an API? For example, send a JSON object from the client to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at P2P, it uses Wifi Direct, so one device can be setup as a host server and the other devices can register to that as clients.
Check out the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct).

Comment: As far as I've read, P2P automatically picks the server. Still, does it support a good number of clients? Say 40?

Comment: As far as I remember there will be one host and then other devices can search and then pick the host which they want to connect to. I only tried it with 4 devices so far, no idea about 40 or so...

Comment: @AhmadSattout The only limit imposed on Wifi Direct by Android is 254 because of the way that IPv4 works. There could be an artificial limit set by the phone manufacturer but that is rather unlikely. Either way: 40 should not be a problem with any recent device.